# Dual Port Server Nic Question

Tags: nic

I'm speccing out a new server that will need to have two physical network connections.  I'm looking at one of these:
http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/us/en/sm/WF06a/15351-15351-3328412-241644-3328421-3884343.html

The information on this server specifically lists one network controller with two ports:

> Network Controller    |    (1) 1GbE NC362i 2 Ports

Will this give me two good network cards or is the additional port merely meant for redundancy and I'd need to purchase an additional Network Controller?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a single network chip (the [Broadcom BCM5709](http://www.broadcom.com/products/Ethernet-Controllers/Enterprise-Server/BCM5709C)); that chip has two ports which can be configured independently, redundantly, or teamed.

It will work just fine for your application.

Answer (score 1):

Unless HP is vastly different from every other server I've purchased, this will give you two ports on one NIC. (or built into the mainboard)  However, both ports are independent of each other.  So it's perfectly suited for connecting to two different networks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a dual port adapter so will present itself as two discrete NICs in the OS (drivers willing). AFAIK you can either team them or have them running on separate networks.

Answer (score 0):

It's a dual port controller, looks to me to based on the [dual port Intel 82576 NIC](http://download.intel.com/design/network/ProdBrf/320025.pdf). From an OS perspective they are seen as two separate NICs.

Someone more familiar with HP can comment about the pro's and con's of this particular implementation but in general Intel's dual port server NICs are very good. It supports most of the server NIC features that I'd usually be looking for - TCP\UDP checksum offload, Receive Side Scaling, iSCSI boot, VLANs, SMBUS and BMC pass through, SR-IOV and VMDq etc.

Comment: It's a Broadcom chip, not Intel.

Comment: Are you sure - http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=3908148&prodTypeId=329290&prodSeriesId=3908147&swLang=13&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4037 . I don't have one in front of me to check but the drivers point to it being the Intel chipset I referenced.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure this will give you two ports. You could set-up teaming if you want, but I use it as two different NIC's in Ubuntu Server.